# Which fonts show the stroke order of all characters?

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, software, stroke-order

For academic purposes, I need to print out some pages of characters with stroke orders shown. Which computer fonts (e.g. TrueType or OpenType) are available which show the stroke order of each character (e.g. by showing numbers near the beginning of each stroke)?

Comment: whose stroke order? chinese, taiwanese?

Comment: @magnetar There is a tag "simplified", so we know it refers to Mandarin.

Comment: Stroke orders do differ even when characters are the same between regions: See 必http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_order#Stroke_order_per_polity

Comment: @Alenanno, Mandarin is a spoken dialect which is writeable both with traditional and simplified characters, just like other dialects such as Minnan (Taiwanese)

Comment: @NannuoLei This site is about Chinese mainly, though, not Taiwanese. If Taiwanese was the language being treated, we'd have that tag.

Comment: @Alenanno I know, but you said that because the tag is "simplified", it has to refer to Mandarin, and that is simply not the case

Comment: @NannuoLei Oh ok... I'll delete the comments soon, they're obsolete anyways. :)

Answer (score 7):

I just started a project to make such a font. You can find it here: http://rtega.be/chmn/index.php?subpage=68

Comment: way to go @rtega! 加油！Keep it up!

Comment: I will. The focus is now on HSK-characters. I basically started the project because I need them for my HSK practice sheets.

Answer (score 6):

No fonts do, just sites with pictures or animations.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:-bw.png#file

  **Instructions**: Past the address in your browser bar, then write a character between "File:" and "-bw", like this "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:你-bw.png#file". It will show you the character's stroke order, not animated, but very clear.
- http://www.visualmandarin.com/tools/dictionary/

  This shows the stroke order but not the stroke direction.

Comment: The wikipedia page you linked seems to be only referenced from the Japanese version of Wikitionary. However, the Japanese stroke order may be different from Chinese.

Comment: @fefe Where did you read that? There's only links to Chinese stuff in the details below. There's also a quick reference to Japanese too, but as a whole project, not for the character itself.

Comment: I didn't read that ... I just happen to see some wikitionary pages like 走([ja](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B5%B0), [zh](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B5%B0)). I checked a few others and only the Japanese version contain the stroke order picture. Oh, I see it is also referenced in several other wikitionaries now. However, though in the origin section it listed reference for several regions, I want to know what will happen when these references don't agree with each other.

Comment: Ok, but that character, when you click in "ja", it specifies it's Japanese and not Chinese, "ja.wiktionary.org/...". That link I provided in the example, belongs to [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Bw.png_stroke_order_images): *"Printable black and white images showing common or specific to China stroke order..."*.

Comment: Oh, finally found [this](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%87%B8), the Japanese version of stroke order seems to use `jbw` when the two are different. The the link you give should be the Chinese version.

Comment: I noticed a similar graphic on the Wikipedia page mentioned. It's an animated gif showing both order and direction. http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E4%BD%A0-order.gif, where you could replace %E4%BD%A0 with other characters (I would assume).

Answer (score 4):

[MDBG](http://mdbg.net) has stroke animations for all the characters, and highlights the radical, but I don't think you can print it out. That said, it's available online, for free, so it gets points for accessibility.

Comment: How do I access this feature?

Comment: @juckele Yeah, i was confused too. You have to look things up in the *character* dictionary (not the word dictionary). Then, click on the button with the arrows to the right of the resulting character, and then click the button with the brush. Then, i think it comes up with a java applet showing stroke order.

Comment: You can also get to this by expanding the characters in the word dictionary it seems.

Answer (score 3):

There is a website called [汉典](http://www.zdic.net/zd/zi/ZdicE7Zdic90Zdic86.htm). It is a dedicated Chinese character dictionary, and now has animated stroke order.

It is (almost) all Chinese though.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't any Chinese font with stroke order. But Japanese has: http://www.nihilist.org.uk, https://sites.google.com/site/nihilistorguk/. And I have to remind you, even one character is the same in Chinese and Japanese, its stroke order may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any fonts with stroke order, but there are some online resources:

- [常用國字標準字體筆順學習網](http://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/home.do) (Learning program for stroke order of frequently
  used Chinese characters)
- [常用國字標準字體筆順手冊](http://www.edu.tw/files/site_content/m0001/bishuen/f8.html) (manual)